# expected `()`, found opaque type for async function

Tags: rust, webassembly, web-sys

I am following [a guide](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/webrtc_datachannel.html) for setting up a WebRTC data-channel with web-sys. I can copy and paste the code and it compiles correctly. The start() function is async which makes it possible to await a [JsFuture](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen_futures/struct.JsFuture.html) inside the main scope, however I am trying to move this await to the `onmessage_callback` block instead. Just by adding this one line to the original implementation I have this:

```rust
  let onmessage_callback =
        Closure::wrap(
            Box::new(move |ev: MessageEvent| {
                let desc = JsFuture::from(pc1.create_offer()).await.unwrap();
                match ev.data().as_string() {
                    Some(message) => {
                        console_warn!("{:?}", message);
                        dc1_clone.send_with_str("Pong from pc1.dc!").unwrap();
                    }
                    None => {}
                }
            }) as Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)>,
        );
    dc1.set_onmessage(Some(onmessage_callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    onmessage_callback.forget();
```

Once I compile this I ofcourse get an error saying that awaiting the future `desc` is only possible inside an asynchronous context. I figured that I could add the `async` keyword when defining the `FnMut` function:

```rust
  let onmessage_callback =
        Closure::wrap(
            Box::new(move |ev: MessageEvent| async { // <-- async
                let desc = JsFuture::from(pc1.create_offer()).await.unwrap();
                match ev.data().as_string() {
                    Some(message) => {
                        console_warn!("{:?}", message);
                        dc1_clone.send_with_str("Pong from pc1.dc!").unwrap();
                    }
                    None => {}
                }
            }) as Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)>,
        );
    dc1.set_onmessage(Some(onmessage_callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    onmessage_callback.forget();
```

But when I compile this I get the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/lib.rs:48:22: 57:14] as FnOnce<(MessageEvent,)>>::Output == ()`
  --> src/lib.rs:48:13
   |
48 | /             Box::new(move |ev: MessageEvent| async {
49 | |                 let desc = JsFuture::from(pc1.create_offer()).await.unwrap();
50 | |                 match ev.data().as_string() {
51 | |                     Some(message) => {
...  |
56 | |                 }
57 | |             }) as Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)>,
   | |______________^ expected `()`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
            found opaque type `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)`
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this, I think the error is saying that the callback returns a future but it should be void instead.

How do I define an async callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is as specified by @nikoss, you pass a future-returning function and cast it to a unit-returning function.

As for how to solve that, you can spawn the future on JS promise microtasks queue with [`spawn_local()`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen_futures/fn.spawn_local.html):

```rust
let (pc1_clone, dc1_clone) = (pc1.clone(), dc1.clone());
let onmessage_callback =
    Closure::wrap(
        Box::new(move |ev: MessageEvent| {
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let desc = JsFuture::from(pc1_clone.create_offer()).await.unwrap();
                match ev.data().as_string() {
                    Some(message) => {
                        console_warn!("{:?}", message);
                        dc1_clone.send_with_str("Pong from pc1.dc!").unwrap();
                    }
                    None => {}
                }
            });
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)>,
    );
dc1.set_onmessage(Some(onmessage_callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
onmessage_callback.forget();
```

Comment: Oh thats awesome as I mentioned I am not familiar with the library and wasn't aware of existence of a bundler runtime with wasm bindgen

Answer (score 2):

You declare that your function will not return anything by saying

```
Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)>
//which is the same thing as Box<dyn FnMut(MessageEvent)->()>
```

then in your callback, you actually return an async block back.

I am not familiar with the library in question but looking at the documentation you are not supposed to pass an async function.

if you must use async and if you have a runtime running already you can spawn a task inside a sync block.

But in javascript world you cant really wait for something if something is async you can only give it a callback (async/await keywords exists but all they do is to return you another promise)

So I believe you should be using the [promise](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.Promise.html) API here and provide a callback for the `then` method.

It is not pretty but this is how things get done in the js world and what you are facing here is called the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) in js which is a thing :D

Ps:
Javascript has a single threaded runtime and things get scheduled on a forever running loop called the event loop. Every time you pass a callback somewhere at some point it gets registered on the event loop and gets called eventually.

What's important to understand is that the calling part of it is not guaranteed and if you were to block event loop in one of your callbacks then next tick of the loop would never come therefore the entire runtime would lock up. this is the reason behind the design decisions that lead to the callback hell

Pps:

I don't really think you should bundle (if even its possible) a rust async runtime with your wasm binary since js has its own as I mentioned just stick with the promise api